# Unable to Get Variable From Subproccess in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am running the command, `netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state` within command prompt, I receive the following output which is expected.

```
Domain Profile Settings:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
State                                 ON

Private Profile Settings:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
State                                 ON

Public Profile Settings:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
State                                 ON
Ok.
```

I am trying to pull the status of the firewall into a function and check weather it is up or not.

I am running the bellow code to get the firewall status. I am just using `print()` commands for now for debugging.

```
import subprocess
import os, sys

def system_check():
    stream = os.popen('netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state').read()
    if ('State' == 'ON'):
        print('Firewall is on')
    else:
        print('Firewall is off')
```

Whether I try to use `'ON'` or `'OK'`, or call `stream` instead of `State`, it still returns `Firewall is off`. I have also tried `if ('State' in stream == 'ON'):` and `if ('State' in stream == 'OK'):`, and still get the same results.

Am I calling the wrong variable, am I doing this wrong entirely?

I am going to need to do this for checking network connectivity, antivirus status, and encryption status, is there a resource that I can use to get the proper variables to call?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: `if ('State' == 'ON')` is just comparing two literal strings, not getting anything from the subprocess. It will never be true.

Comment: **Am I calling the wrong variable** You're not using any variable in the `if` statement.

Comment: You need to split `stream` into lines, check whether the line begins with `State`, then check whether the second word is `ON` or `OFF`. Your code doesn't do any of that.

Comment: You seem to be expecting the computer to read your mind about how to parse the output. You have to write all the parsing code yourself.

Comment: There are also 3 different `State` lines. Which is the one you want to use?

Comment: BTW, this isn't C, you don't have to put the `if` condition in parentheses.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I will try and update the question.

Comment: Side note, I am aware that I do not have to add parentheses, it is just force of habit. I had luck with it working with and without.

Comment: As for your question, I would like to use all three.

Comment: So is the firewall on if any of them is ON or only if all of them are ON? The `any()` or `all()` functions might be helpful to you.

Comment: If one of them is off, then it would be reporting that.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just test whether the output contains the word `OFF`.

```
def system_check():
    stream = os.popen('netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state').read()
    if 'OFF' in stream:
        print('Firewall is off')
    else:
        print('Firewall is on')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I very much appreciate it.